# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013). Send Email using PHP Mailer via new Gmail App password

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Recently Google disabled the feature of allow off less secure apps for SMTP Authentication. I got to know that I have to use an App Password from my google account. I did all the instructed documentation from a blog, but I can't send an email using PHP mailer. I am not able to figure out the error.

The Code I have tried :

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes at the top
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// Instantiation
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
// Server settings
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure= 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->Username = 'uqureshi269@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'akuocvvdclceirgi';
// Sender &amp; Recipient
$mail->From = 'uqureshi269@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'SENDER NAME';
$mail->addAddress('dqureshiumar@gmail.com');
// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$body = 'This is a test message';
$mail->Body = $body;
if($mail->send()){
  echo 'Success Message';
  exit;
}else{
  echo 'Error Message';
  exit;
}
?>
```

Below is the error I am facing:

```
2022-09-02 19:04:12 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. in D:\xampp\htdocs\scrap-bike\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:2214 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\scrap-bike\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(2003): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\scrap-bike\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1662): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Fri, 2 Se...', 'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHR...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\scrap-bike\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1500): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\scrap-bike\mail.php(38): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #4 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\scrap-bike\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 2214
```

Comment: You have done everything correctly. But some time windows didn't permit to connect with outsider network using socket connection. That's why you should allow php for administrator permission. 
If you don't do it, then you should use local mail server for testing such as mailhog. 
I use mailhog for local mail testing

Comment: How do I have to allow php for administration permission? A blog might be helpful

Comment: As Ariful said, you need to fix your server config. You should not disable certificate verification (what's in `SMTPOptions`); if you're having trouble with gmail's certificate, it's your server's problem, not gmail's, so fix your server (most likely by updating your OS packages, see the troubleshooting guide for more info) rather than leaving yourself open to interception of your traffic.